# How to get values from custom liquid radio button on product page to show up on the cart in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am new to Shopify and I have created a custom liquid section on my product page to show different colors of my product that is available. How do I display the option that is selected by the customer, when the customer adds the product, to their cart?

This is my custom liquid section:

```
<input type="radio" id="grey" name="rbtnColors"> Grey (Default)
<br>
<input type="radio" id="beige" name="rbtnColors"> Beige
<br>
<input type="radio" id="white" name="rbtnColors"> White
<br>
<input type="radio" id="black" name="rbtnColors"> Black
<br>
<input type="radio" id="brown" name="rbtnColors"> Brown
<br>
<input type="radio" id="clear" name="rbtnColors"> Clear
<br>
<input type="radio" id="clear_blue" name="rbtnColors"> Clear Blue
<br>
<input type="radio" id="clear_red" name="rbtnColors"> Clear Red
<br>
<input type="radio" id="clear_green" name="rbtnColors"> Clear Green
```